# Order Form Total with PHP Mailer

Tags: javascript, phpmailer

We are building an interactive order form for a catering service where the total updates on the screen, then the details are all ordered to the restaurant manager using PHP Mailer.

Everything works great except we cannot get the total to be sent in the email. The total is generated via javascript as people fill out the form.

We believe that the solution is to somehow show the total within a hidden div or input that PHP Mailer will recognize, but we are struggling with how to do that, or even if that is the correct answer.

Here is a [link to the site](http://mariamaria.website/banquets-dv/) and the code is below. Thanks!

Note: I put both "total" and "emailTotal" in the email form to see if either would work. We want this to simply be the dollar amount of the order.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$message=
'
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" border="1" style="width:100%;">
<tr border="1">
<td>DANVILLE BANQUET REQUEST</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr border="1">
<td sytle="width:25%">
<strong>Client:</strong>
</td>
<td sytle="width:25%">
'.$_POST['inputName'].'
</td>
<td sytle="width:25%">
<strong>Day & Time:</strong>
</td>
<td sytle="width:25%">
'.$_POST['date'].'<br />
'.$_POST['time'].'
</td>
</tr>
<tr border="1">
<td><strong>'.$_POST['pickupOrDelivery'].'</strong></td>
<td></td>
<td><strong>Guests:</strong></td>
<td>'.$_POST['guestnumber'].'</td>
</tr>
<tr border="1">
<td>
<strong>Phone:</strong>
</td>
<td>'.$_POST['inputPhone'].'</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr border="1">
<td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
<td>'.$_POST['inputEmail'].'</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr border="1">
<td>
<strong>Package:</strong>
</td>
<td>
<strong>'.$_POST['menu'].'</strong><br />
</td>
<td>
<strong>'.$_POST['room'].'</strong><br />
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr border="1">
<td>
<strong>Extras:</strong>
</td>
<td>
'.$_POST['guac'].'<br />
'.$_POST['quesadillas'].'<br />
'.$_POST['floutas'].'<br />
'.$_POST['ducktacos'].'<br />
'.$_POST['nachos'].'<br />
'.$_POST['roastedcorn'].'
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr border="1">
<td>
<strong>Desserts:</strong>
</td>
<td>
'.$_POST['flan'].'<br />
'.$_POST['limePie'].'<br />
'.$_POST['cremeBruleeCheesecake'].'

</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<strong>Notes:</strong>
</td>
<td>'.$_POST['notes'].'</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<strong>Total:</strong>
</td>
<td>'.$_POST['total'].'</td>
<td>'.$_POST['emailTotal'].'</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
';
```

(skipping php mailer code and most of the order form)

```
<div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                    <div class="total">
                      <h2>Total: $<span id="total"></span></h2>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                      <input type="hidden" name="emailTotal" value="help" />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name="submit" value="Submit Request" />
                  </div>
                </div>
```

And finally the relevant js:

```
var total = (banquetPrice * numGuests) + (9.5 * numGuac) + (9.5 * numQuesa) + (9.5 * numNachos) + (9.5 * numFloutas) + (12.5 * numDuckTacos) + (4.5 * numRoastedCorn) + (7* numFlanP) + (7* numKeyLimeP) + (7 * numCheesecakeP)
    console.log(banquetPrice)
    $("#total").html(total.toFixed(2));
    console.log(total)
```

Comment: You'll have to port your Javascript's calc formula to PHP, that's the more secure option you have, trust me. Just make sure to send all the data you need to make the calculus in your form's submission.

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden form field is named `emailTotal`, but your JS is referencing `$("#total")` - just change it to `$("#emailTotal")` and you should be OK.

Comment: I created emailTotal to be a separate variable to potentially use in a hidden field, under the assumption that we can't just call total a second time. I'm guessing that's a mistake...

Comment: Yes, I see that, but you don't set its value in your JS code, hence the problem.

Comment: Like this? `$("#total").html(total.toFixed(2));
    $("#emailTotal").html(total.toFixed(2));`

Comment: `emailTotal` is a form field, so use `val()` to set its value rather than `html()`.

Comment: Just spotted - you also need to add `id="emailTotal"` to the form field. Hopefully that'll do it.